# UploadFileAsync with Foreach

Tags: c#, file-upload, foreach, webclient

I have:

```
 foreach (FileInfo fileinfo in Arquivos)
               {
                   float zz = (float)fileinfo.Length;
                   zz = (zz / 1024f) / 1024f;
                   label8.Text = "sending: " + fileinfo.Name + "("+zz.ToString("0.0")+"MB)...";
                   label8.Update();
                   WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                   client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
                   client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
                   client.UploadFile(new Uri("ftp://" + ftp + "/" + caminho + "//" + fileinfo.Name), "STOR", pasta + mes + fileinfo.Name);
                   bar++;

                   backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(bar);
               }
```

And I need create a UploadProgressChanged, so I have:

```
client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
```

And

```
 private void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
           progressBar2.Update();
       }
```

UploadProgressChanged not work with UploadFile, just UploadfileAsync, but I need send 1 file per time. How can I change UploadFile to UploadFileAsync and send a file per time?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only able to send 1 file at a time then why are you concerned about using Async? You also seem to be using a background worker to do all the work.

Might you not be better off spinning up a 'Task' for each file to be uploaded, and kicking them off with a scheduler that only allows one task at a time?

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx

That way you could make use of some the newer Task and async methods available while simplifying your task.

---

Based on further analysis if you want to run them asynchronously but only do one at a time:

```
    private AutoResetEvent _fileUploadedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private void DoUploadBackgroundWorker()
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            client.WhenUploaded += (s, e) =>
                {
                    // This signals the AutoResetEvent that it can continue
                    _fileUploadedEvent.Set();
                };
            client.UploadAsync();
            // This will keep ticking over every 15 milliseconds to check if the
            // AutoResetEvent has been triggered
            while (_fileUploadedEvent.WaitOne(15)) { }
            // We get here when it's been triggered (which means the file was uploaded)
            // So we can update the progressbar here and then move onto the next file.
        }
    }
```

It needs expanding and the classes aren't all correct as I've just knocked this together, but it should provide enough material to start you in the direction.

Comment: Well, I'm new in C # and yes, I run the foreach inside backgroundwork. What I need is to create a progressbar for each uploaded file because it is large files.